# Function not printing the plot in R

Tags: r

I have a function called 'branch' which outputs a plot with a line from point a to point b. The function is just a rearragement of the lines() function in R, and it works fine.

Now, I am trying to loop that function so it draws a line with its origin in the point where the first line ended, in other words, point 'b' of the old line becomes point 'a' of the next line, and the length of the new line is half the length of its parent's length.

```
drawLine <- function(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y, color='white') {
  start  <-   c(start.x,end.x)
  end    <-   c(start.y,end.y)
  line   <-lines (start, end, col=color)

  return(line)
}

branch <- function(origin,length, color='white'){
  branch <- drawLine(origin,100,origin+length,100, col = color)
    return(branch)
}

par(bg = "black", mar = c(0,0,0,0))
plot.new(); plot.window(xlim=c(0,400),ylim=c(0,400))
branch(100,100, 'white') #notar, color default es blanco
branch(200,100, 'red')
```

You can check up to here that it works.

```
tree <- function(origin, length, numberOfBranches, color = 'white'){
  numberOfBranches <- vector()
  branches <- list()
    for(i in numberOfBranches){
        branches[[i]] <- branch(origin,length, col = color)
        origin = origin+length
        length = length/2
    }
  return(branches)
}
```

For some reason the console is only printing the empty list "list()"

It is worth mentioning that the y-axis is fixed at height 200, so it is not a scaling problem.

Why is it not plotting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without `branch`, how are we to know what's going on?

Comment: ```branch``` is just a rearrangement of lines() native R function.

Comment: Sure, Camus, please don't take offense to this ... many "simple functions" written by well-intending analysts have a critical bug or miscalculation. You are saying the problem is that `branch` calls are not showing any lines, so it would help to either (1) show the function, or (2) adapt your process here to use just `lines` and see if the problem remains.

Comment: Forget that, I see a problem. You call with `numberOfBranches=200` and then immediately reset it with `numberOfBranches <- vector()`.

Comment: Camus, before going any further, fix your `numberOfBranches` overwrite and test again. Even if there's another problem, this one is just an "obvious oops" to me.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!!! You were right, it was just a oops moment! I uploaded the full code nevertheless. Thanks a lot for your patience.